# Are there any known ways to combat involuntary volume fluctuations in speaker hardware?

Tags: audio, logitech-speakers

My logitech X540 system is occasionally having its volume fluctuated - at random without my doing and this happens regardless of what device is streaming music through it.

In a [Logitech forum](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/Speakers/Logitech-X-540-volume-fluctuations/td-p/191586/page/2), one user suggested the following:

```
open remote control
disassemble volume and bass control potenciometers.
dismantle the potenciometers with bending 4 little holders.
clean and exchange the potenciometers boards
(optionally bend a little the small sheets which are touching the board
at the plastic part of the potenciometer)
put everything back
enjoy the sound!
```

Should I follow this user's advice or are there other more effective workarounds or fixes?

Comment: If you're asking here, you're probably asking for hardware/software related answers. This being said, and since you said the problem occurred regardless of device (therefore, drivers, I suppose) maybe there is a problem in the power feed. Other than this, the problem seems more electronic than hardware related, as described in the help pages.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like some serious business. I'll give my answer, but it might not be exciting or correct. I noticed my speakers were doing this too, but it was Windows doing it. To check go to your sound settings and select the communications tab and make sure when it detects activity, it is set to "Do nothing".
[image]

Comment: It seems like your answer would only affect calls and the OP stated the problem as with music stream.

Comment: you'd think it would only be from calls, but that wasn't the case. I noticed it would randomly do it when I play SC2.

Comment: Interesting solution, however it didn't solve the problem. I'm afraid Doktoro may be right in this being an electronic issue

Answer (score 1):

By disabling these advanced features in the Soundblaster Recon 3Di control panel:

- THX TruStudio Pro 'Smart Volume' and
- CrystalVoice 'Smart Volume'.

I found that the volume was stable after that.

I discovered this because I was going to follow the advice to stop Windows reducing the volume during communications activity.  When I went into the sound menu and looked at the devices, Windows flashed up a dialogue box saying it had detected a conflict with some of the advanced features of the driver I was using and it asked if I wanted to revert to the Windows preferred driver.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem with my X-540 (11 years old) connected to a PC. Increasing the volume above 50% (mine is at ~55%) from the volume knob seems to have fixed it. For a second day now there are no issues.

**Source:** https://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/825614-logitech-x-540-volume-fluctuates/

**Edit:** Two months later, still no problems.